# Call dialog.dismiss after the successful login toast message which will hide the dialog

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

Can someone show me how to dismiss the dialog because i am trying with `dialog.dismiss()` 
and `alertdialog.dismiss` but i am getting an error that it cannot resolve symbol and also access and use the input for Email and Password that would really help

```
package com.example.marcusgrant.test12345;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Console_Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.console_login);


    final ImageView xShowDialog = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.XboxImBtn);


    ImageView pShowDialog = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.PsnImBtn);


    xShowDialog.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            AlertDialog.Builder mBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Console_Activity.this);
            View mView = getLayoutInflater(). inflate(R.layout.xdialog_signin, null);

            final EditText XEmail = (EditText) mView.findViewById(R.id.etEmail);
            final EditText Xpassword = (EditText) mView.findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
            Button XLogbtn = (Button) mView.findViewById(R.id.Logbtn);
            Button XNtnbtn = (Button) mView.findViewById(R.id.ntnbtn);

            XLogbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(!XEmail.getText().toString().isEmpty() && !Xpassword.getText().toString().isEmpty())
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(Console_Activity.this, R.string.successful_login, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        xShowDialog.setImageResource(R.drawable.xboxbuttongreen);

            //cannot resolve symbol 'alertdialog'
             dialog.dismiss();


                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(Console_Activity.this, R.string.error_login_message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });




            XNtnbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                     //cannot resolve symbol 'alertdialog'
                    alertDialog.dismiss();
                }
            });



            mBuilder.setView(mView);
            AlertDialog dialog = mBuilder.create();
            dialog.show();

        }
    });

}



  }
```

Comment: Well, you dont have `alterDialog` variable declared in your code. You probably want to use `dialog.dismiss()` in place of that

Comment: I tried that in the first onclicklistener

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to actually declare the variable before you use it. For the code, inside the `onCreate()` it gets executed sequentially and therefore you will have to declare the `dialog` variable before using it ..

Change your code to something like this :

```
        ...
        final EditText XEmail = (EditText) mView.findViewById(R.id.etEmail);
        final EditText Xpassword = (EditText) mView.findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
        Button XLogbtn = (Button) mView.findViewById(R.id.Logbtn);
        Button XNtnbtn = (Button) mView.findViewById(R.id.ntnbtn);

        // Changes here
        mBuilder.setView(mView);
        final AlertDialog dialog = mBuilder.create();


        XLogbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(!XEmail.getText().toString().isEmpty() && !Xpassword.getText().toString().isEmpty())
                {
                    Toast.makeText(Console_Activity.this, R.string.successful_login, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    xShowDialog.setImageResource(R.drawable.xboxbuttongreen);


         dialog.dismiss();


                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(Console_Activity.this, R.string.error_login_message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });




        XNtnbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                 //changes here
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        //changes here
        dialog.show();

    }
```